# React Native Scrollview not adjusting to small height changes

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a React Native App, which has a ScrollView as a root tab and a 'react-native-tab-view' TabViewAnimated (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view)  as the child with multiple tabs.

When the application runs in iOS, the ScrollView adjusts to the individual tab height and keeps growing if I switch to a Tab with more content but, it does not shrink when I visit a tab with less content, showing a lot of 'empty-space'.

The Child Component ('TabViewAnimated') has {flex : 1} and I have also set automaticallyAdjustContentInsets to true for the ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#centercontent):

> ### centerContent bool
>
> When true, the scroll view automatically centers the content when the content is smaller than the scroll view bounds; when the content is larger than the scroll view, this property has no effect. The default value is false.

---

If not try other properties from that page for your Scroll View. Good luck.